# Fill field in textField From UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i want to make a texField , when i click on it , a UIDatePickerView appear ...
I maked this

```
@interface getDatesAndPriceController : UIViewController {

    UIDatePicker * deparatureDate ;
    UITextField *deparatureField;

}
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker * deparatureDate ;
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet  UITextField *deparatureField;
```

in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    deparatureField.inputView=deparatureDate;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

But i don't work :( . When i run the UIdatePicker directly appear and when i click the textField the keyboard appear . Help please

Comment: Two things. Don't make the `UIDatePicker` subview of the view. Make it a sibling to view controller's view. Second, its most likely the outlets aren't wired up.

Comment: @Deepak  , thakyou but i'm so soryy i don't understand what do you mean :(

Comment: Are the outlets set up correctly?

Comment: @Deepak Ah it's right , it was not seted up correctly :) thank you . But to make a "Done" button when the date is choosed i should make a UIToolbar ?

Comment: Yes, I added an image to explain the first part.

Comment: @Deepak It's the last question :D how to do to make the UItollbar appear Wehn the Picker appear ?

Comment: `departureField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to answer to show what I am saying. The `UIDatePicker` is not a subview to the view. So if you wish you can even create it programmatically. I also added a toolbar with a done button which is necessary in dismissing the keyboard. This will be the text field's input accessory view. Once you have set up all the outlets correctly, the date picker will show up instead of the keyboard.

[image: Setup]